# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based

Tags: hibernate

```
public void testis() {
        Staff2 emp = new Staff2();
      emp.setName("SFFF");
      emp.setType("yyy");
      emp.setDme(123);
      emp.setIsActive("FFF");
   ssiMasterValidationSearchCriteriaDaoImpl.save(emp);

    }

private final static String SAVE_TO_DB="Insert into table1 (name,type,code,mne) values ('?','?','?','?')";


    public void save(Staff2 employee){
        Object result = getHibernateTemplateExt().uniqueResultBySQL(
                SAVE_TO_DB,
                new Object[] {
                    employee.getName(),
                    employee.getType(),
                    employee.getDme(),
                    employee.getIsActive()});

    }
```

getting the title error
that is

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Remember that ordinal parameters
>   are 1-based!  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:55)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:61)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:397)

Comment: change private final static String SAVE_TO_DB="Insert into table1 (name,type,code,mne) values ('?','?','?','?')"; to private final static String SAVE_TO_DB="Insert into table1 (name,type,code,mne) values ('?1','?2','?3','?4')";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `private final static String SAVE_TO_DB="Insert into table1 (name,type,code,mne) values ('?','?','?','?')";` to `private final static String SAVE_TO_DB="Insert into table1 (name,type,code,mne) values ('?1','?2','?3','?4')";` and check.

Also I suspect your query `Insert into table1 (name,type,code,mne) values ('?','?','?','?')` contains fields which are different from these setters

```
  emp.setName("SFFF");
  emp.setType("yyy");
  emp.setDme(123);
  emp.setIsActive("FFF");
```

For example `setDme` field name should be `dme` but in query it is `mne`